# How to change font color for a text logo that is a PNG file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, logo, png, file-format

I have a client that sent me their logo as a .png file.  However the text color needs to be changed.  Is there a way to convert to an illustrator file and change the color?  I tried image trace then save it as a .ai file but the text was cut off in spots.

I'm obviously a developer over a designer so would really appreciate any tips on this.

Thank you..

Comment: Do you have Photoshop available for use?

Comment: I would ask the client for a vector file of their logo, if this is not an option I would do this in Photoshop (or recreate the logo in Illustrator if that's an option).

Comment: Sorry, I missed your answer... yeah the client has had her logo for a long time... I don’t think she has it in vector. I’ll just change it out in photoshop. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want this converted to a vector format (which is probably not that easily doable with a single step, like an image trace in AI), you'll probably do this quicker in Photoshop, but keep it in PNG format - even better if the PNG is transparent.

Just open the PNG in Photoshop, select around the text, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, tick Colorize, then play with the sliders.

Comment: Thank you...worked perfectly in photshop!

Comment: One additional question...is there a way to select 1 word and change that to a different color?  Thanks

Comment: We have not seen your logo to give a specific 'yes', but generally in Photoshop you can limit selections to just about anything you need to. Use the Marquee tool to only select those particular words that need to be edited, then the color change will only apply to whatever is being selected.